# using LIKE command in Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_CheckGlobalizationResourceValue
 (
   @ResourceObject NVARCHAR(255),
   @ResourceName NVARCHAR(128)
    )

AS

select count(*) from vpglobalizationresources
      where ResourceObject = @ResourceObject and 
ResourceName like '%' + @ResourceName + '%'
```

And I'm using Linq to SQL classes. I send ResourceObject and ResourceName from .cs file which is shown above. And it's returnValue is always 0 why? Is there something wrong in stored procedure or cs class? I ran this query in database and it works fine there.

```
public static bool CheckGlobalizationResourceValue(string resourceObject, string resourceName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dataContext = new ResourceDBDataContext())
            {
                resourceObject = resourceObject.Replace(ConfigurationHelper.MainDirectory + "\\", "");
                resourceObject = resourceObject.Replace("\\", "/");
                //resourceName = string.Format("'%{0}%'", resourceName);

                var result = dataContext.sp_CheckGlobalizationResourceValue(resourceObject, resourceName);
                if ((int)result.ReturnValue == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
                //return (int)result.ReturnValue != 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occured when retrieving data from database");
        }
    }
```

Comment: And I also removed the stored procedure from my .dbml file and added it again after changing it.

Comment: give me data & structure for table to better understand...

Comment: It is pretty difficult to say since I don't know what `dataContext.sp_CheckGlobalizationResourceValue` is doing, and I am not overly familiar with LINQ, but based on the fact you use `result.ReturnValue` I expect you are referencing what the stored procedure returns rather than what its results. By default a stored procedure has a return value of 0 unless you override it with something like `RETURN 1;`.

Comment: I fixed it by this query in stored procedure! IF EXISTS(select *
  from vpglobalizationresources
  where ResourceObject = @ ResourceObject and 
  ResourceName like '%' + @ ResourceName + '%')
  return 1

  else return 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your stored procedure. I guess you need to use `like` statement in ResourceObject filtration

```
select count(*) from vpglobalizationresources
      where ResourceObject like @ResourceObject and 
ResourceName like '%' + @ResourceName + '%'
```

It's also may be problem with sleshes in @ResourceObject. Just try to execute `Select` with real values of parameters and check is there is some data returns back or not

Comment: I debugged in .cs file and checked their values in database. Everything works fine if i write that query in database and run. So both resourceobject and resourcename has the correct values. I think there is something wrong in .cs side of calling this.